# SQL Server: how to count records returned from Top 50 percent query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I get counts of records returned by Top 50 % select query.

```
select top 50 percent * 
from Customers
```

I tried to use below query

```
select count(*)/2 
from Customers
```

but it is not accurate as it will return 45 records when total number of records in table is 91 while TOP 50 percent query returns 46.

I need a query which can tell number of records returned by `select TOP 50 percent * from Customers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap it with subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select TOP 50 percent * from Customers) s
```

or by using windowed COUNT:

```
select TOP 50 percent *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt from Customers
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use COUNT and get a more exact result with decimals:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/2.0 FROM customers
```